# VIM: navigating xdebug traces

Tags: vim, xdebug

The xdebug traces look like this, :

```
1 TRACE START [2011-12-06 12:50:29]
2     0.0018     350384   -> {main}() /index.php:0
3     0.0019     350464     -> error_reporting() /index.php:4
4     0.0019     350704     -> define() /index.php:8
5     0.0021     370136     -> require_once(/forum/global.php) /index.php:43
6     0.0022     370216       -> error_reporting() /forum/global.php:13
7     0.0020     353760       -> chdir() /index.php:42
8     0.0019     350704     -> define() /index.php:9
9     0.0019     353760     -> dirname() /index.php:42
```

Each time a function or include() is called, the third column indents another place. For instance, in line 5 we see a require_once(/forum/global.php) in which the error_reporting() and chdir() functions are called, and then code flow returns to the original file (/index.php).

How can I jump down from a line for a file (say line 5 which is in /index.php) over the include()ed files to the next line of the file (which would be line 8 in the above example).

One solution that I could think of would be to overload "j" to look check that it is not on a space character, and if it is then to run "j" again. If there is a better solution then I would love to know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file you gave, you can jump around the lines with the specific position of "->" you're interested in (at columns 29-30) using the following search by regular expression:

Search pattern:  `/^.\{28\}-`

Here are the details:

- `/` is the search key
- `^` means start of line
- `.\{28}` means 28 random characters
- `-` just matches "-" as the next (29th) character

After typing this search once, you can navigate around the lines you're interested in using `n` (forwards) and `N`(backwards).

-- edit --

Based on the comments below, here's another version closer to what the O.P. was looking for:

Ex command: `:exe '/^.\{'.(col(".")-1).'\}->'`

This builds on the previous search pattern, using the value of the column right before the cursor instead of a fixed value.

Comment: Thanks. That would be tedious in it's current form, but it might work if I could replace 28 with the current column and map it to a shortcut. Googling for current column vim doesn't return anything that looks usable, however. Do you possibly know how I could get the current column to use that in a map? Thanks!

Comment: @dotancohen Trying a bit more showed that the following may be closer to what you want: `:exe '/^.\{'.col(".").'\}-'` , to be executed when cursor is placed in front of the "->". If this works for you, I'll add it to the actual answer.

Comment: Thanks! I moved the cursor one place over, like so: `:exe '/^.\{'.(col(".")-1).'\}-'` such that I can now `0f-` to the first dash from anywhere on the row and then run the search. I'll map this to something. Your solution is terrific. I did find the `col(".")` bit online but I had no idea that I would have to add the `exe` bit to the front. That will surely help me in the future for other scripting as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: @dotancohen Glad it helped! Answer now edited based on the previous comments, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally related, but I use `debugger.vim` for debugging PHP code, and find it invaluable.

You can ge the script here, or a slightly modified version at my github

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1929

https://github.com/richo/richo-vim/tree/master/plugin